# Dyanmaically load script and js based element or selector exist

Tags: javascript, dynamic, load

For example, I have a `page1.html` with this code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>page1</title>
</head>
<body>
 <select style="width:100%" class="select2">
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```

and have a `myscript.js`

```js
$('.select2').select2({
  allowClear : true,
  width : '100%'
});
```

Now, I want to load dynamically `select2.min.js` where `.select2` class located. what should I do?

Comment: As it appears you're using jquery, have a look at [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for loading scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of questions:

[Clear dropdown using jQuery Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240047/clear-dropdown-using-jquery-select2)

[Select2 allowClear not working with dynamic dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433594/select2-allowclear-not-working-with-dynamic-dropdown-list)

and many more... If not, please explain more regarding the functionality you are trying to achieve.

If you want to load that particular script into the page dynamically, then Ajax is the way - but is not loaded 'where .select2 class located'.

Comment: this is incorrect, you don't understand completely. select2 plugin is example. I want to load plugin.min.js each script dynamically

Comment: Can you provide the scenario please. Why and where it needs to be loaded, and what change it should make to what part of the UI when it is. You have stated you want to load a script into a class attribute...